# How do the cross-platform windows frameworks like Qt work? Are they wrappers around native API?

Tags: c++, cross-platform

Are QT/WxWidgets wrappers around respective native APIs' on linux, windows and Mac?

How are cross-platform windows framework built? How is cross-compiling done?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, and how it's done is by writing complicated, very hard C++ code, over the course of many years. That's the only way to do it.

Comment: If you want more details, the source code to both of those libraries are available for your perusal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

Sometimes they use lower level APIs to generate their own implementation of higher level APIs; like one that uses OpenGL to implement non-OS widget library.  At other times they could adapt/reskin/modify OS widgets.

They are usually not cross-compiled.  They just build and provide a similar API on multiple platforms, allowimg "client" code to compile with fewer changes on multiple platforms.